# What do I need to know about this rubber stopper?

Tags: parts, replacement, identify-this-bike

I recently bought a used Diamondback Sorrento.  One day I rode it over a sizable bump and heard a popping noise.  Upon inspecting my bike I noticed the following:

[image]

As far as I can tell, I lost a rubber stopper that protects the shocks from dust/water/etc.  What exactly is it called?  How important is it that I replace it?  Do I need to worry about protecting the inside of my shocks until I do?

Comment: Short term very temporary fix is to put some tape over it to keep dirt and dust out.   If you have a spare cork (wooden or plastic) that may make an adequate bung too.  The longer you leave it, the more shite will end up in the wrong place.  Go do it now.

Comment: Have you covered it yet?   Not a permanent fix, but the longer you leave it open, the more contaminated it will get.

Comment: @Criggie I have, but just with Scotch tape.  I hope to implement a slightly more elegant solution in the future.  I happened to notice that the inside is already a bit rusted though (assuming from a previous owner).

Comment: Good man - Procrastination is the enemy of.... something.... which I'll look up later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your particular shock, it is as you guessed just a cover to keep out dirt. Replacement parts for these shocks are generally not available. I would suggest a visit to a local hardware store and find a generic rubber /plastic plug that will fit in the hole.

Comment: Might be worth a trip to a bike shop first, to see what they might have.  But a plastic "goof plug" from a hardware store should do the job reasonably well.

Comment: The LBS may have a bin of random bits 'n pieces that they can rummage in to find something that will fit.